# create records with associations in sequalize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i have the following model in sequelize.

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {

_id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},
name: DataTypes.STRING,
email: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  unique: {
    msg: 'The specified email address is already in use.'
  },
  validate: {
    isEmail: true
  }
},
role: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  defaultValue: 'user'
}
}
```

the model has some asssoications/relations as follows:

```
User.belongsToMany(models.Skill, {through: 'UserSkill', as: 'Skills'});
```

to save a new record i use the following request payload:

```
{
 "name": "Test User",
 "email": "d3@ddd.com",,
 "skills" : [2,3]
}
```

where skills should represent an array of ids for skills we already have in DB, how can we save the new record and validate all skills at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This is the one way may be it helps you :)

```
router.post('/assignSkills', function (req, res, next) {
var record = req.body.data;
model.users.findOne({
    where: { id: record.userId }
}).then(function (user) {
    model.skills.findOne({  
        where: { id: record.skillId }
    }).then(function (skill) {
        user.addSkill(skill);
        res.send(user);
    });
});
});
```